# Unity Failed to Build apk Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, sdk, java-9

i followed the unity "tanks!" tutorial and now i'm trying to port the game on Android, it's my first time on Unity, now when it's going to build the APK unity tells me "Failed To Build APK" and then i get some errors, i'm attaching you the error i think it's fatal, please tell me what's wrong with it.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-9.0.1\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -D com.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Android_SDK\tools" -D file.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar"-

stderr[
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
            at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
            at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
            at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
            at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
            at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
            at UnityApkBuilder.<init>(UnityApkBuilder.java:214)
            at UnityApkBuilder.main(UnityApkBuilder.java:34)
            ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
            at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 11 more
]
stdout[

]

exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 emoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 emoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you execute `jdeps` on your application, you would be able to see that `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` has been deprecated and can be replaced with **[`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)** which is there since JDK 1.8.

The *[migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F7696E02-A1FB-4D5A-B1F2-89E7007D4096)* reads this as well :

> A few `sun.*` APIs have been removed in JDK 9. Notably,
>   `sun.misc.BASE64Encode`r and `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` have been removed.
>   Instead, use the supported `java.util.Base64` class, which was added in
>   Java SE 8.

---

In your case, since you rely on third parties(android sdktools) which themselves haven't resolved this. I'm afraid you might have to stick with 1.8 and in the meanwhile, this can be reported to their trackers once they plan to migrate their artifacts.

Of course, this also means you would have to at some point in time *upgrade to using their Java 9 compatible version of the jar* if and when they plan to release.

***Update*** : This can be tracked on ***[Unity#956425](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-builds-fail-with-java-9-jdk-and-unable-to-list-target-platforms-error)*** for further updates.

Comment: Someone should submit a bug to the Android SDK to fix this dependency, it will not otherwise run on new JDKs.

Comment: @AlanBateman Ya agreed. Let me dig in more to see if such a bug already exists. Otherwise, would file one and update the answer.

Comment: i have not used any jdk code, maybe should i download jdk 8? because i think it's not supported by unity...

Comment: Well currently since you rely on third parties(using/built on java) which themselves haven't resolved this. Seems, *yes you might have to stick with 1.8* OR look for a way in which you can specify the custom JDK to the build that you're creating. @AlanBateman Any other alternates to suggest maybe?

Comment: sun.misc.BASE64* were always JDK internal, never documented. Finally removed in JDK 9. There is no secret flag to make this come back.

Comment: Solved using JDK 8.

Comment: @MarcoCauli Yup that seems to be the current solution to me as well. Have linked the bug tracker from Unity in the answer though.